# Rate of change taylor series

Tags: calculus

I am wondering how this is derived:

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=R(x,h)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x)+h f'(x)$$

I want to fully understand what is going on here, I would like to see the step by step derivation of this expression.

Comment: What is known about $R(x,h)=f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h-\frac12f''(x)h^2$?

Comment: The term "rate of change" is irrelevant, "remainder term" or "error term" is  better.

Comment: Start with the mean value theorem and integrate by parts, taking f and its derivatives as the first function each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the Taylor series for $f(x)$

$$f(x) = f(x_{0}) + f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0}) + \frac{1}{2!} f''(x_{0})(x-x_{0})^{2} + R(x,h)$$

with $R(x,h)$ your higher order terms. Now, you are expanding around the point $x_{0} = x$. Then, as the original argument for our function $f$ is actually $x+h$, we map $x \mapsto x+h$ and hence

\begin{align}
f(x+h) &= f(x) + f'(x)(x+h-x) + \frac{1}{2!} f''(x)(x+h-x)^{2} + R(x,h) \\
&= f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{1}{2!} h^{2}f''(x) + R(x,h)
\end{align}

rearranging, we find

$$f(x+h) - f(x) = hf'(x) + \frac{1}{2!} h^{2}f''(x) + R(x,h)$$

Comment: Why would f(x+h) =f(x) .... and not f(x+h), second I am not able to verify R(x,h), I realise tha I have accepted the answer but I would really appreciate if you could explain this as well?

Comment: @ALEXANDER I think you are just getting confused by notation. You just need to be aware of what each aspect of the Taylor series represents. Try mapping $x \mapsto x+h$ (i.e changing the argument) _first_, **then** set $x_{0}=x$ (i.e determining the point of expansion) if that helps. The $(x-x_{0})^{k}$ terms are just a translation from $x_{0}$ to the origin. The $R(x,h)$ is just your higher order terms (remember, the Taylor series is an _infinite_ series) i.e

$$R(x,h) = \frac{1}{3!} h^{3} f'''(x) + \frac{1}{4!} h^{4} f''''(x) + \frac{1}{5!} h^{5} f^{(v)}(x) + ...$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\displaystyle f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^{2}}{2!} f''(a)+
\int_{a}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^{2}}{2!} f'''(t) \, dt$

or alternatively, $\displaystyle
f(x+h)-f(x)=hf'(x)+\frac{h^{2}}{2!} f''(x)+
\int_{0}^{h} \frac{t^{2}}{2!} f'''(x+t) \, dt$

Can be easily verified by doing backward, with integration by parts, on the remainder term.